# How to use bash $(awk) in single ssh-command?

Tags: bash, ssh, awk

I am trying to execute a single command over `ssh` that contains `sub-code` or $(sub-code) (I use it all the time but I don't know the official name for that) to be executed first, but on the target server.

For the sake of argument, let's say this is the command I want to use. Ofcourse this can be done with `hostname`, but this is just a simplified example that contains all the formatting wizardry I want to use.

```
echo `uname -a | awk '{print $2}'`
```

No problem. But how do you escape this properly to send it over `ssh` in a single command? The following is wrong, because it lets the server reply your local hostname. The sub-code is executed locally:

```
ssh myServer echo `uname -a | awk '{print $2}'`
```

But any escape-ishness that comes to mind doesn't work:

```
$ ssh myServer echo \`uname -a | awk '{print $2}'\`
awk: cmd. line:1: {print $2}`
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ invalid char '`' in expression
$ ssh myServer echo \$(uname -a | awk '{print $2}')
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
$ ssh myServer echo \$\(uname -a | awk '{print $2}')
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
$ ssh myServer echo \$\(uname -a | awk '{print $2}'\)
awk: cmd. line:1: {print $2})
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I would like an answer that includes using properly escaped `` ` or $() because I'd like to know if it's possible. ``echo` could be something more complicated.

Comment: why `echo \`command\``? why not `command`?

Comment: @anishsane because he wants to see how to pass a backtick or a `$(` through ssh to a remote server

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Try this

```
ssh myServer "uname -a | awk '{print \$2}' "
```

Use the double quotes `"` in order to group the commands you will execute remotely.

You also need to escape the `$` in the `$2` argument, so that it is not calculated locally, but passed on to `awk` remotely.

Edit:

If you want to include the `$(` `)`, you again have to escape the `$` symbol, like this:

```
ssh myServer "echo \$(uname -a | awk '{print \$2}') "
```

You can also escape the *backtick* `, like this:

```
ssh myServer "echo \`uname -a | awk '{print \$2}'\` "
```

Comment: @Redsandro I think I figured out how to escape the `$(` and the backtick on ssh. Just updated my answer...

Comment: If you execute in sub-command like `res=\`ls | awk '{print \\$2}'\``, we need two escape here.

Comment: Yeah I was trying sshpass to execute /proc/loadavg on remote server and using awk to filter the result.  Thanks for the answer. The escape sequence did the trick!. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

It is better to use a **heredoc** with `ssh` to avoid escaping quotes everywhere in a more complex command:

```
ssh -T myServer <<-'EOF'
uname -a | awk '{print $2}'
exit
EOF
```

Answer (score 6):

### Just some additional note:

#### In my case, the escape of the `$` doesn't help:

```sh
ts1350:> ssh sysadm@node "grep feature features.txt| awk '{print $6}' "
Password: 
A  feature   -name  ue_trace_mme    | off
ts1350:> ssh sysadm@node "grep feature features.txt| awk '{print \$6}' "
Password: 
awk: cmd. line:1: {print \}
awk: cmd. line:1:        ^ backslash not last character on line
awk: cmd. line:1: {print \}
awk: cmd. line:1:        ^ syntax error
ts1350:> ssh sysadm@node "grep feature features.txt| awk '{print \\$6}' "
Password: 
awk: cmd. line:1: {print \\}
awk: cmd. line:1:        ^ backslash not last character on line
awk: cmd. line:1: {print \\}
awk: cmd. line:1:        ^ syntax error
```

#### While add a `space` between `$` and the number works:

```sh
Fri Oct  4 14:49:28 CEST 2019
ts1350:> ssh sysadm@node "grep feature features.txt| awk '{print $ 6}' "
Password: 
off
```

Hope this secodnary way help someone like me.

Thanks to @dave in his answer: [How to print a specific column with awk on a remote ssh session?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294820)

Comment: While add a space between $ and the number works, this is amazing, thank you very much. I tried \' \$, almost everything, still does not work, frustrated.

Answer (score 5):

What about piping the output of the command and run awk locally?

```
ssh yourhost uname -a | awk '{ print $2 } '
```

Comment: Thanks, this works in certain cases. However, for more versatility, user000001's answer does exactly what I want. :)

Answer (score 4):

The workaround is to create an sh file with the command then pass it to ssh command:

**test.sh**

```
echo `uname -a | awk '{print $2}'`
```

and command:

```
ssh myServer 'bash -s' < test.sh
```

**UPDATE**:

The command without quotes works fine as well:

```
ssh myServer uname -a | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: @"The command without quotes works fine as well:" the awk being executed is local awk, not on the remote system.

Comment: Yes, commands from all 3 questions run the right part (after the pipe) locally. So the only solution is to save the command in the script.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Upvoted. But user000001 does exactly what I want in a single command, I've accepted that one. :)

Comment: "So the only solution is to save the command in the script" : I object the "only" word. probably you meant "easiest".

Comment: sorry, I mean answers. I've tested the last command of user000001 and it works on the remote server so I was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to get the hostname, use:

`ssh myServer "uname -n"`